# binary operator + , = overloading with const

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am learning C++ concepts and would highly appreciate any help with explanation. Why statement 4 is not compiling but statement 1 is.

```
class X {
    public:
            X& operator= (const X& rhs);
            const X& operator+ (const X& rhs) const;
            const X& operator+ (int m);
    private:
            int n;
};

int main() {
        X a, b, c;
        a = a + 5 + c; //statement 1 - No compiler errors
        a = b + 5; //statement 2
        a = a = b + c; //statement 3
        a = b + c + 5; //statement 4 /*compiler Error thrown -
passing 'const X' as 'this' argument of 'const X& X::operator+(int)' discards qualifiers
 [-fpermissive]*/
        (c = a + a) = b + c; //statement 5
}
```

As per my understanding (based on: both + & = are right-associative) above 5 statements are deciphered as-

```
//statement 1
a.operator=(a.operator+(5.operator+(c)));
```

-->I believe this should have thrown error as no defined constructor supports this

```
//statement 2
a.operator=(b.operator+(5));

//statement 3 
a.operator=(a.operator=(b.operator+(c)));

//statement 4
a.operator=(b.operator+(c.operator+(5)));

//statement 5
(c.operator=(a.operator+(a)))=(b.operator+(c)); then
lhs_result.operator=(rhs_result);
```

Also Did I correctly decipher statement 5th above?

Comment: `+` is left-associative. `a + b + c` is `(a + b) + c`. Also, `operator+` should normally return `X` by value rather than a reference.

Comment: The **unary** `+` is right associative, addition is left associative.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that statement 4 would be compiled then declare the operator like

```
const X& operator+ (int m) const;
```

The problem is that in this statement

```
a = b + c + 5;
```

b + c is a const object. See the corresponding operator declaration

```
        const X& operator+ (const X& rhs) const;
```

You may not for a const object call a non-const member function.

Take into account that additive operator + groups left to right. 
From the C++ Standard (5.7 Additive operators)

> 1 The additive operators + and - group left-to-right.

As for statement 5

```
(c = a + a) = b + c; //statement 5
```

then it has undefined behaviour because evaluations of operands of the assignment operator are not sequenced.
So either at first expression (c = a + a) will be evaluated and then expression b + c.
Or expression b + c at first will be evaluated and only then expression (c = a + a)

Answer (score 0):

### The compiler error

```
a = b + c + 5;
```

Your `operator +(int m)`  is not marked `const`. That is what the compiler error is telling you. You should also return just `X` as `+` calculates a new X value.

```
X operator+ (int m) const;
```

Will fix that.

### Operator associativity

Only operator = is right-associative. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

### Order of evaluation

1. Your Statement 1

   a.operator=(a.operator+(5.operator+(c)));

> I believe this should have thrown error as no defined constructor supports this

There are no constructors involved here.

4. Statement 4

   a.operator=(b.operator+(c.operator+(5)));
   Should be

   a.operator=(b.operator+(c).operator+(5))
5. Statement 5

   (c = a + a) = b + c;
   Since the assignment is inside a parenthesis this takes precedence over associativity. I.e. the `c = a + a` is evaluated before the `= b + c`.

   (c.operator=( a.operator+(a) ).operator=(b.operator+(c))

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1 does this :

```
a.operator+(5).operator+(c)
```

This works, because the `operator+` that takes an `X` is `const`, and hence works on the `const` temporary returned by `a.operator+(5)`.

Statement 4 does this :

```
b.operator+(c).operator+(5)
```

This doesn't work, because the `operator+` that takes an `int` is not `const`, and hence doesn't work on the `const` temporary returned by `b.operator+(c)`.

Both `operator+` need to be `const` to make this work :

```
X operator+(const X& rhs) const;
X operator+(const int& m) const;
```

Note I also changed the operators to return by value instead of by reference. That's how it's supposed to be (the result of an addition of two numbers is a new number after all).

Answer (score 0):

Statement one is equivalent to `a.operator=(a.operator+(5).operator+(c));`
So that's perfectly valid.

For statement 4 however, the `operator+ (int m)` method has to be const. Meaning: `const X& operator+ (int m) const;`

Statement 5 should be equivalent to: `c.operator=(a.operator+(a)).operator=(b.operator+(c));`

The errors and warnings of clang when compiling your code are very helpful, I recommend using it for such experiments. Its error and warning messages are very good:

```
test.cpp:15:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const X' and 'int')
  a = b + c + 5; //statement 4 /*compiler Error thrown -
      ~~~~~ ^ ~
test.cpp:4:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const X' for 1st
      argument
  const X& operator+ (const X& rhs) const;
           ^
test.cpp:5:12: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const X', but method is not
      marked const
  const X& operator+ (int m);
           ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: clang indeed gives more descriptive error message. Where/How to get this compiler?

Comment: clang is the C/C++ fronted for LLVM. You can download it here: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.5 If you are running Debian GNU/Linux or Ubuntu, `apt-get install clang` is also possible, might however be an older version. For more info, see: http://llvm.org What's especially helpful is that you can call clang like gcc for the most part. E.g. `clang -o test test.cpp`